# mail not sending to hotmail and gmail

Tags: email, centos, gmail, hotmail, exim

i have a problem with sending email from my server to hotmail and gmail. seems the mail is just dropped, no returned bounce email notices etc. the emails just vanish. I have looked around for solutions on the net but nothing seems to help. below are the email headers of one mail which is send correctly to another big provider, without any problem. As i cant make any sense of it as to why hotmail is rejecting these mails, i hope someone can make something of it and give me directions on maybe a solution:

```
Return-Path: <s----@----.nl>
Delivered-To: <s----@ziggo.nl>
Received: from md2.tb.mail.iss.local ([212.54.34.152])
by mc7.tb.mail.iss.local (Dovecot) with LMTP id lQqGGXGJuFUZJAAAqQNqOQ
for <s----@ziggo.nl>; Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:10:01 +0200
Received: from mx24.gn.mail.iss.as9143.net ([212.54.34.152])
by md2.tb.mail.iss.local (Dovecot) with LMTP id lPAPLTGvolV/XgAAH7GgQA
; Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:12:41 +0200
Received: from mail.lastikweb.eu ([185.10.49.172])
by mx24.gn.mail.iss.as9143.net with esmtps     (TLS1.2:DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:256)
(Exim 4.82)
(envelope-from <s----@----.nl>)
id 1ZKMR6-0001UG-T6
for sleenheer@ziggo.nl; Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:10:00 +0200
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1] helo=aicit.nl)
by mail.lastikweb.eu with esmtpa (Exim 4.76)
(envelope-from <s----@----.nl>)
id 1ZKMR6-0001R8-EW
for s----@ziggo.nl; Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:10:00 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;
format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 10:10:00 +0200
From: s----@----.nl
To: s----@ziggo.nl
Subject: mail headers
Message-ID: <8670b9ca857e112fbc307d29ee84ccb2@aicit.nl>
X-Sender: s----@----.nl
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.9.5
X-Ziggo-spamsetting: Instelling=Gemiddeld Scorelimiet=14
X-Ziggo-spambar: /
X-Ziggo-spamscore: 0.0
X-Ziggo-spamreport: CMAE Analysis: v=2.1 cv=DeLq0aZW c=1 sm=0 tr=0     a=cWpRTkv7rqSFuHP3f9xSTw==:17 a=XVisR3dVAAAA:8 a=cIF5Tx0qAAAA:8 a=drCK43fGrOkA:10 a=IkcTkHD0fZMA:10 a=zOBTXjUuO1YA:10 a=nS36O97Bj3wUElCrIrAA:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10   xcat=Undefined/Undefined
```

none
   X-Ziggo-Spam-Status: No
   X-Spam-Status: No
   X-Spam-Flag: No

test

I have dkim installed, tested all settings with mxtoolbox (dns, smtp etc) al seems to be right, but still Hotmail and Gmail is not accepting emails from my server (which holds about 25 domains, all sending through this server).

thanks!

Comment: Can you check your gmail delivery sessions in exim logs (`exim_mainlog` , `exim_rejectlog`), there might be some useful info there

Comment: this is last piece of my mainlog as this ends up as spam: 1ZKPqk-0000EI-Od <= stefan@aicit.nl H=localhost (aicit.nl) [127.0.0.1] P=esmtpa A=login:stefan@aicit.nl S=551 id=dcccec47ec87b74ad8d229783b94bb44@aicit.nl T="wederom" from <stefan@aicit.nl> for leenheersjc@gmail.com
2015-07-29 13:48:43 1ZKPqk-0000EI-Od => leenheersjc@gmail.com F=<stefan@aicit.nl> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=572 H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4013:c01::1b] X=UNKNOWN:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1438170523 cb3si43376530wjc.44 - gsmtp"
2015-07-29 13:48:43 1ZKPqk-0000EI-Od Completed

Answer (score 0):

Gmail ending up in spam is related to designated user not being able to send out through main server. case you have server: mail.server.com and you are sending mail with my.domain.com, the spf record needs to hold the ip6 of mail.server.com in spf. Obviously rDNS needs to be correct. For the hotmail problem, this is purely microsoft. you can check up with support from outlook.com, but only thing you get is "we dont block your server, although some emails are filtered. this can be caused by mitigation time, which can take up to 48 hours". Thats it. No messages are returned, simply dropped. Maybe msn.com outlook.com and live.com are experiencing the same problem.